# Show that $(\phi^G)_K=(\phi_{H\cap K})^K$ where $HK=G$ and $\phi$ is a class function of $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

Question: Let $H,K\subseteq G$ with $HK=G$ and suppose $\phi$ is a class function of $H$.  Show that $(\phi^G)_K=(\phi_{H\cap K})^K$

Thoughts: Define $\dot{\phi}(g)=\phi(g)$ if $g\in H$ and $0$ otherwise.  If I want to play with the LHS first, then my idea was to take $\displaystyle (\phi^G)(g)=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{x\in G}\dot{\phi}(x^{-1}gx)$, and then restrict it to $K$, but I am not getting anywhere with that.  So, I think it may be best to play with the RHS first.  So, $\displaystyle (\phi_{H\cap K})^K(k)=\frac{1}{|H\cap K|}\sum_{y\in K}\dot{\phi}(y^{-1}ky)$.  Now, $|H\cap K|=\frac{|H||K|}{|G|}$, so if I can split this sum up a bit and write it as an induced character where I can pull out $\frac{1}{|K|}$ and $\frac{1}{|H|}$, then that could clear up the constant stuff, but I can't quite "make a map" that would help clear some of this up.  I've fully convinced myself this is true (woop-dee-do) but I can't make anymore progress on it.  Any help?

Comment: Do you have a version of the induction formula that sums over a transversal rather than the whole of the group?

Comment: Certainly!  Suppose $\{g_1,\dots ,g_n\}$ is a left transversal for $H$ in $G$, then $\theta^G(g)=\sum_{i=1}^n \dot{\theta}(g_i^{-1}gg_i)$.  I used this tactic for 5.1, but I couldn't get it to be of use here for whatever reason.

Comment: How do you prove that $|HK|/|H|=|K|/|H\cap K|$ (if $HK$ is a subgroup)?

Comment: Since $|G|=|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$, and so divide by $|H|$.

Comment: You have just rearranged the formula. How do you prove the formula for $|HK|$ in terms of $|H|$, $|K|$ and $|H\cap K|$?

Comment: Write $HK=\cup_{h\in H}hK$ and so $|HK|=|K|\cdot |\{hK:h\in H\}|$.  Then show $h_1K=h_2K$ iff $h_1(H\cap K)=h_2(H\cap K)$. So the order of the set above is precisely the number of distinct cosets $h(H\cap K)$.  Apply Lagrange and the order of the set above is $|H|/|H\cap K|$.

Comment: Prove it using transversals. Then link this with the previous question I asked. It should give you ideas about why the formula works.

Comment: Ah, okay, so if I prove it using transversals, then I can use the above to "bridge the gap" to get the stuff in terms of $H\cap K$, right?  I'll try and write up a proof and post tomorrow.  Thank you!